# unable to get the index of element in array react js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, find

```
  const editAddHandler = (event, key) => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    onValue(ref(db, `users/${userId}/addressData`), (snapshot) => {
      const addresslist = [];
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const keyName = childSnapshot.key;
        const data = childSnapshot.val();
        addresslist.push({ key: keyName, data: data });
      });
      props.setSavedAddress(addresslist);
    });

    console.log("array of element",props.savedAddress)

    const clickedAddress = props.savedAddress.findIndex(element => element === key)
    console.log("clicked key",clickedAddress)
        
    const keyValue = props.savedAddress[key];
    console.log("keyvalue",keyValue)
    
    console.log("key",key)

    if(key === props.savedAddress[key]) {
      setValues({
        name: props.savedAddress[key].data.name,
        phone: props.savedAddress.phone,
        pincode: props.savedAddress.pincode,
        address: props.savedAddress.address,
        city: props.savedAddress.city,
        state: props.savedAddress.state,
        landmark: props.savedAddress.landmark,
        defaultAdd: props.savedAddress.defaultAdd,
      })
    }
    props.showAddressHandler();
  };
```

[image]

unable to get the index of props.savedAddress list, need to compare the index and key onClick event.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

Comment: The key is a string, and props.savedAddress is an array of objects with a key property, instead try     `const clickedAddressIndex = addresslist.findIndex(element => element.key === key);`

Comment: Your `addresslist`  contains objects. Comparing objects with `===` has very specific rules, ie it returns true if and only if it's the very same object (ie pointing to the same location in memory). Furthermore `if(key === props.savedAddress[key])` doesn't seem to be too usefull either ...

Answer (score 0):

const clickedAddress = props.savedAddress.findIndex((element,i) => i === key)

this will give the index